# Find the shortest line from input (C)

Tags: arrays, c, string

I made a function that counts all characters of every line I get from input. Code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int countAllChars (char inp[])
{
    int charCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; inp[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(inp[i] == '\n' || inp[i] == EOF) {
            continue;
        } else {
            charCount++;
        }
    }
    return charCount;
}

int main ()
{
    int total = 0;
    char inp[1000];

    while(fgets(inp,100,stdin)) {
        printf("%d\n", countAllChars(inp));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This works as intended, e.g. with the text file **input.txt**, which contains:

```
Password
longpassword
short
aaa
verylongpassword
```

and the following **syntax** for running the program:

```
./binary <input.txt
```

My program prints out:

```
8
12
5
3
16
```

Which is correct. My objective now is to print out the **number of characters** of the **shortest** line of the said file. Using the above example, I know that the shortest line has the character count of **3**. My question is, how do I get this exact value? I thought about saving the value into another variable, and then check that variable against another callings of the function, which **yielded the following code:**

```
int countAllChars (char inp[])
{
    int charCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; inp[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(inp[i] == '\n' || inp[i] == EOF) {
            continue;
        } else {
            charCount++;
        }
    }
    return charCount;
}

int main ()
{
    int total = 0;
    int shortestLine = 0;
    char inp[1000];
    while(fgets(inp,100,stdin)) {
        shortestLine = countAllChars(inp);
        if(shortestLine < countAllChars(inp)) {
            shortestLine = countAllChars(inp);
        }
    }
    
    printf("Shortest line is --> %d\n", shortestLine);

    return 0;
}
```

Not only is the code pretty ugly and obfuscated, but it doesn't work correctly, too. Running the code on the same text file (**input.txt** with the content above) prints out:

```
Shortest line is --> 16
```

Which is obviously not correct.

Comment: Just keep track of the smallest so far and update when you get a smaller line

Comment: @klutt That was exactly my line of thought, and I thought that my code accomplishes this. But it doesn't.

Comment: `countAllChars` is implemented incorrectly. When it sees a `'\n'` character in the `inp` buffer, it executes `continue`. That continues the `for` loop, going on to the next value of `i`. That is wrong, because it continues counting characters in the buffer after the `'\n'`. Instead, you want to `break` from the loop, ending it. Also, testing for `EOF` is wrong. `EOF` is not a character, and `fgets` never stores it in a buffer.

Comment: The code you show to remember the shortest line length is also flawed. You have `shortestLine = countAllChars(inp);` before you have tested whether `inp` currently is the shortest line. Instead, use `int currentLineLength = countAllChars(inp);`, then decide whether or not `currentLineLength` is the shortest length seen so far. If it is, then update `shortestLineLength`. (Note: `shortestLineLength` is a better name than `shortestLine` because its value is a length, not a line.)

Comment: When fixing the code to remember the shortest line length, you will need to think about how to handle the first line. At that point, there is no previous shortest line length. There are different ways of handling that, which is something you should consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting chars in the same line twice and always re-assign the `shortestLine` undconditionally:

```
    while(fgets(inp,100,stdin)) {
        shortestLine = countAllChars(inp);
        if(shortestLine < countAllChars(inp)){
            shortestLine = countAllChars(inp);
        }
    }
```

Initialize a variable which holds your "winner" and use another variable to keep track of the length of the current line:

```
#include <limits.h>

int shortestLine = INT_MAX;
int currentLineLength = INT_MAX;
while(fgets(inp,100,stdin)){
    currentLineLength = countAllChars(inp);
    if(currentLineLength < shortestLine) {
        shortestLine = currentLineLength;
    }
}
```